# IIS gives 503 after updating .NET 4.0 to beta 2

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.0

I just removed Visual Studio 2010 beta 1, and installed the Beta 2 on a win 2008 Web Server.

After performing this, my application pools fails to start. I manually edited the application pools, and selected the new .net 4.0 framework. But when I start the application pool, and request a page in an application in that pool, I get a "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

If I look at the application pools in IIS, I can see that it has now stopped. Going to the event viewer I find this error message:
The worker process failed to pre-load .Net Runtime version v4.0.20506.

Now - there we have the problem. Build no 20506 is the beta 1 version. Beta 2 has build 21006. So for some reason, even though I updated the application pools to use the new installed .NET framework, it still tries to load beta 1.

So where is this setting stored, and how do I change is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running aspnet_regiis /i from the 21006 framework folder.  That should re-register it with IIS7.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Strange, it wasn't necessary to run when I installed the beta 1. Why didn't beta 2 just override that setting, I wonder.

Comment: Great, glad that worked.  Beta 2 likely intended to do it but it failed somewhere in the process and just needed a nudge in the right direction.  It normally updates the references correctly.